# Restrict URL not to change after promise rejects in resolve function of Angular UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have routes

```
.state('staff.dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'demo2.html',
        })
.state('staff.users.institutions', {
            url: '/institutions',
            templateUrl: 'demo.html',
            resolve: {
                security: [
                    '$q', 'UserFactory', 'AuthenticationService',
                    function ($q, UserFactory, AuthenticationService) {
                        UserFactory.setData(AuthenticationService.getUserData());
                        if (!UserFactory.hasInstitutionsUsersAccess()) {
                            return $q.reject(App.errors[401]);
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        })
```

And on error I have

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        if (error === App.errors[401]) {
            $state.go('staff.dashboard');
        }
    });
```

So the scenerio is:

- When I change URL **/institutions** before logging to app, it changes the URL to **?url=%2Fdashboard** because of the security in **Institutions** state.
- What I want is to keep the URL as **?url=%2Finstitutions** after **$q** rejected in **resolve**.

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your toState and/or fromState params :

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    if (error === App.errors[401]) {
        $state.go('staff.dashboard', {"url" : fromState.url});
    }
});
```

Then you can access your url param in your dashboard :

```
app.controller('dashboardController', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    var fromUrl = $stateParams.url;
});
```